# Voltage Rating of Capacitor Set Up

Tags: voltage, capacitor, basic

A buddy of mine just told me that the set up (linked to the question on Circuit Lab) would be able to handle 500 volts DC, even though each capacitor is rated for 20 volts DC. It was to my understanding that voltage would only add in series. Is he correct, or could the set up only handle 100 volts DC?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fApSSa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Next time someone claims something, you should ask them to walk you through their reasoning. I can't think of any reasoning, incorrect or otherwise where 500V would come from.

Comment: @DKNguyen I did, he explained that voltage for capacitors also adds in parallel. I googled it later and didn't see anything for voltage ratings increasing in parallel, so naturally I came here.

Comment: Ah, they don't. That's flat out wrong. Parallel caps increase the max ripple current (since they share the ripple current).

Answer (score 6):

Your friend is incorrect.  It's not even guaranteed that this setup would handle 100V, as component variation could mean voltage imbalance between caps and one cap could see more than 20V.  (You sometimes see large value resistors placed across series caps to balance the voltage.)

Answer (score 4):

If your caps are random 10% tolerance , the design rating is reduced to 90V absolute max.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, it's good for 100.  He probably multiplied twice, or used a V**2 term as though he were calculating power.  Keep in mind it's only 100V if the caps in each row are absolutely identical.